# 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

Given the following MySQL table "tallamedida":

```
(FK)idProducto/(FK)idTalla/(FK)idMedida/valor/tolerancia/observaciones
```

Trying to add data to it using php:

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    echo $_POST['productosel'];
    $insertar = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tallamedida (idProducto, idTalla, idMedida, valor, tolerancia, observaciones) VALUES ('".$_POST['productosel']."', '".$_POST['selecttalla']. "', '".$_POST['selectmedida']."', '".
        $_POST['valormedida']."', '".$_POST['tolerancia']."', '".$_POST['observacion']."')",$con);
    if($insertar){
        echo "Exito Insertando <br>";
    }else{
        echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Produces the following error:

> 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wakas`.`tallamedida`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Talla_has_Medida_Producto1` FOREIGN KEY (`idProducto`) REFERENCES `producto` (`idProducto`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I've tried replacing the $_POST['productosel'] for an existing value in the table "Producto" where the FK is inherited from but the error still persists.

Double checked data integrity and all fields are added using existing values.

Comment: All these fields are mentioned as foreign keys. (FK)idProducto/(FK)idTalla/(FK)idMedida. Do you have related data for all three fields ?

And try to run SHOW CREATE TABLE tallamedida; So you can see the real table structure and foreign key relationships.

Comment: Please keep personal statements, 'thank you', and requests for help out of your posts.

Comment: First need to check datatype of idProducto is same in both table may be signed or unsigned integer issue and check which idProducto you are inserting in tallamedida table that is already exist in producto table.....